# Would a question requesting recommendations for easy-to-learn/beginner level languages/frameworks be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, rules

For example: I have zero experience coding functional GUIs. I would like to know, in general, which languages/frameworks for GUIs have features x,y,z, are relatively easy to learn, etc.

In general, are questions similar to this allowed? If so, what qualities would make it an appropriate post versus one that would be deleted/edited?

Comment: Have you checked the help center a bit and tried to answer that yourself? What's unclear with the current guidance in the help center and related pages? :)

Comment: We have a close reason for such questions: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Also, "easy to learn" would also likely get the question closed as primarily opinion based. You'll want to read the pinned articles under "Asking" in the [help] to answer your general question.

Comment: @Patrice Nothing is wrong with the help center. I just didn't know it existed/where to find it. Now that you mentioned it, I found it and will definitely use it. Thank you!

Comment: I doubt that any software could be described as 'easy to learn'.  GUI framework or not, it will still require testing and debugging:(

Comment: Learn to program first. Learn to program GUIs second. You need the fundamentals to be able to do a good job, and it also makes understanding everything else easier so you can learn faster.

Comment: Even if such questions were allowed, it would go nowhere. The answer to your question would be: take your pick. We don't live in the 90's anymore, you'll be better off asking what not to use instead as the list is way smaller. Such a question will be perfectly acceptable somewhere else on the web, I'm sure if you post it in Reddit's [learnprogramming](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/) subreddit you will get *mountains* of conflicting recommendations (use C#, no don't! Use Java, no don't!). And then you will still have to take your pick.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, this would not be appropriate to ask.